# Write from maple to a text file

Tags: maple

I have the following code in maple:

```
K:= log(x);
for j from 2 by 1 to 10 do evalf(subs(x=j,K)) end do;
```

I want to write each x and log(x) value to a TEXT File in 2 columns.
Any help please ?

Comment: Please join us here area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107315/maple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John M's answer is more general in that it should work in any version of Maple from Maple 6 onwards, but if you happen to be using Maple 2015, 2016, or 2017, then you could use the [Export](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=Export) command which autodetects the format from the file extension:

```
M := Matrix(9,2):
for j to 9 do M[j,1] := j+1; M[j,2] := evalf(log(j+1)); end do:
Export("C:\\Users\\yourname\\Documents\\MyFile.csv", M);
```

or if you want a one-liner:

```
Export("C:\\Users\\yourname\\Documents\\MyFile.csv",Matrix(9,2,(i,j)->`if`(j=1,i+1,evalf(log(i+1))))):
```

Comment: Please join us here http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107315/maple

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to assign these values to a nx2 Matrix and then [ExportMatrix](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ImportMatrix) it to text file:

```
M := LinearAlgebra:-RandomMatrix(10, 2);
ExportMatrix("C:\\Users\\yourname\\Documents\\FileName.txt",
              M, target = MATLAB, mode = ascii);
```